# Как кэшировать пришедший токен?

Tags: java, android

Я отправляю запрос с imei на сервер,  и получаю токен.
Но при выходе из приложения , и запуске его снова выдается новый токен, мне нужен только 1. И чтобы всегда я работал только с одним, как решить данную проблему?

```
   if(sPref==null) {
       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl("http://tkachenkodevelop.ru/autoexpert/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();

       mServerApi = retrofit.create(API.IServerApi.class);
       //mServerApi = API.getRetrofit(getString(R.string.api_url), this).create(API.IServerApi.class);

       Call<Token> call = (Call<Token>) mServerApi.getToken(imei);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
               // response.body().getAccessToken();

               Log.d("qwe", response.body().getAccessToken());
               //mPhoneEdit.setText(response.body().getAccessToken());
               mToken = response.body().getAccessToken();
               saveText(mToken);
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
               //Log.d("error",t.toString());
           }
       });

   }else {
       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SavedIdToken", MODE_PRIVATE);
       mToken = sharedPreferences.getString("Token", "");
   }
```

где ,

```
void saveText(String token) {
     sPref = this.getSharedPreferences("SavedToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
     ed.putString("Token", token);
     ed.apply();
}
```

Comment: Смотрите последний вариант в ответе в вопросе-дубле

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вопрос является дубликатом точно не того, что вы отметили.

Comment: Сохраните его куда-нибудь. В файл ,в базу данных, в SharedPreferences.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если один из ответов содержит ответ также и на этот вопрос, это не значит, что вопрос является дубликатом.

Comment: @metalurgus, ОК, снял дубль)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб поможете?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нужна помощь с обновлением токена, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @MartinezToni, задайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сохранить в SharedPreferences:

```
//так записываешь
SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("userdetails",
             MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
edit.putString("token", token).commit();
```

Дальше при запуске приложения проверяешь:

```
token = userDetails.getString("token", "null");
    if (!token.equals("null")) {
        //если токен уже есть, то выполняешь действия без авторизации
    } else {
        //если токена нет, то авторизация
    }
```

При логауте удаляешь/ записываешь "null" заместо токена:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
//очищаешь 
edit.clear();
//записываешь null
edit.putString("token", "null");
```

Comment: Запись при Destroy?

Comment: @MartinezToni, при получении токена.

Comment: ошибку выдает: 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: при логауте?Это где?

Comment: @MartinezToni в какой строчке ошибку выдает? Ну я так понимаю логаут не нужен, поэтому просто записывай токен.

Comment: Посмотри код, который я скинул, пожалуйста

Comment: Получается, при полном закрытии приложения и новом запуске генерируется новый токен, как с этим бороться?

Comment: @MartinezToni, у тебя условие (if sPref == null) не правильно. надо сделать так:  sPref = this.getSharedPreferences("SavedToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); и потом условие - if(sPref.getString("Token", "null").equals("null")){ оставляешь как у тебя} else{ также как у тебя}

Comment: @MartinezToni, таким образом у тебя при запуске токен будет браться из SharedPref, а в случае если его там нет, он будет получаться с сервеера

Comment: sPref = this.getSharedPreferences("SavedToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); - где это сделать?

Comment: Вот, ты это имел ввиду?
http://pastebin.com/vYsvs4kH

Comment: @MartinezToni да

Comment: А что делать если токен временный и его нужно обновлять раз в час